# pyspark: Use JavaObject StructType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to parse a [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org) file to create a `pyspark.sql.types.StructType`. I have found a [scala library](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/spark-json-schema) which can do this for me. So I'm calling it like this:

```
f = open('path/to/schema.json')
js = f.read()
conv = dspark.sparkContext._jvm.org.zalando.spark.jsonschema.SchemaConverter
schema = conv.convertContent(js)
```

But when I try to use it to build a `DataFrame` like this:

```
spark.read.format("json").schema(schema)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 103, in schema
    raise TypeError("schema should be StructType")
TypeError: schema should be StructType
```

If I print the type:

```
print type(schema)
```

I get:

```
<class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'>
```

How do I wrap the value as a python `StructType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around in the pyspark source I looked at the implementation for `DataFrame.schema`:

```
@property
@since(1.3)
def schema(self):
    if self._schema is None:
        try:
            self._schema = _parse_datatype_json_string(self._jdf.schema().json())
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise Exception(
                "Unable to parse datatype from schema. %s" % e)
    return self._schema
```

The method `_parse_datatype_json_string` is defined in `pyspark.sql.types` so this works:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import _parse_datatype_json_string

conv = self.spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.zalando.spark.jsonschema.SchemaConverter
jschema = conv.convertContent(read_schema)
schema = _parse_datatype_json_string(jschema.json())
src = src.schema(schema)
```

Now when I call:

```
print type(schema)
```

I get:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.types.StructType'>
```